# Closing over prototypes?

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype

Since there is a benefit to use prototype for methods if you need to create lots of them, do you get the same effect and benefit when you create an object with methods that close over *"this"* in the constructor function?

See the following code:

```
(function(){


    var Planet = function(){

        var self = this;


        var API = {
            publicInterfaceMethodA:function(){
                self.privateProtoMethodA();
            },

            publicInterfaceMethodB:function(){}
        };

        return API;

    };



    Planet.prototype = {

        privateProtoMethod:function(){  },
        privateProtoMethodA:function(){  },
        privateProtoMethodB:function(){  },
        privateProtoMethodC:function(){  },
        privateProtoMethodD:function(){  },
        privateProtoMethodE:function(){  }

    };


    var mars = new Planet();




}());
```

Let's say I have 100 *"private"* methods on the prototype, for every instance I create I only want to expose these few public api methods, but I want to retain the benefit of using the prototype for internal methods so that I dont "copy" 100 methods to *"this"* for every instance created.

From what I can see, this is not how people usually do it, am I missing something here or do you get the same benefit without returning *"this"* in the constructor and exposing the entire prototype?

Thanks

Comment: Inheritance in javascript is one area where you absolutely must do lots of background reading. Unless you are a total genius, you won't even identify all the issues, let alone find workable solutions. Douglas Croskford's [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I started to develop seriously in JS, I also often used the `var self = this;`, because I was used to it from the various jQuery tutorials and I also tried your approach and others to simulate private methods.

Personally I don't like both anymore.
While it is true that `mars` is not an instance of `Planet`, this is - in my opinion - not a real problem, because I normally test for api features and not that often if an object is an instance of a certain constructor.

To private methods/members: when your projects grows and becomes larger you probably want to start to do unit tests. If  you e.g. have `100` private methods and *only*  `10` public ones, creating good unit test can become really problematic. For unit test you would like to test as less dependencies as possible.
Thats why I changed my mind and preferred to create a clear documentation of api with jsdoc  using the annotation to mark methods/members if they are private instead of not over really hiding them.

Sometime it could also be useful not just be able to replace public methods base on the situation, but also private ones.

There are for sure valid situations for your approach, but if you *just* use it to protect the function from misuse, you probably should think about it.

To the `var self = this;`: As long as `someFunction.bind(element)` does not create performance problems I prefer to use `bind` (there is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for older browsers). With that you can avoid deep nesting of e.g. callbacks and you don't need to keep in mind that you need to use `self` where the *expected*  keyword would be `this`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
(function(){
    var Planet = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.constructor.methods = {
            A: function(){ console.log('Constructor Method A called'); },
            B: function(){  },
            C: function(){  },
            D: function(){  },
            E: function(){  }
        };

        var API = {
            publicInterfaceMethodA: function(){
                return self.constructor.methods.A.call(this);
            },

            publicInterfaceMethodB: function(){}
        };

        return API;
    };

    var mars = new Planet();
    mars.publicInterfaceMethodA();
}());
```

The methods are attached to the `Planet` function and then called by the `mars` instance.